# Gets a reference to the clicked item when DoubleTapped is triggered

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8

This is my code when a single tap was suppose to be used:

```
void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = ((SampleDataItem)e.ClickedItem);
}
```

Now I have to perform same when User DoubleTapped/Double Clicks

I tried:

```
private void itemGridView_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = ((SampleDataItem)e.OriginalSource);
}
```

But it is not returning the same object i needed instead it is returning Image,
I want the same object when it was returned @ e.ClickedItem in DoubleTapped Event
please help
and sorry for my poor english

Windows 8 apps, Visual studio2012, Xaml and C#

Comment: Why are you using `DoubleTapped` instead of `SelectionChanged` for `GridView` ?

Comment: because i want to run my application when it is doubleTapped

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
private void itemGridView_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = ((SampleDataItem)e.OriginalSource).DataContext;
}
```